# Can't Stop Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, coroutine

Guys When I gave it something tagged with pizza first coroutine doesn't stop How Can I stop it?

Please help me guys I couldn't find the way. What should I do? Btw I am new sorry for bad posting:/

I'm trying to make a pizza restaurant game. So customer will sit then waitforpizza coroutine will start if we give tag with pizza waitforpizza coroutine should start then eatpizza will start but my waitforpizza doesn't stop.

```
IEnumerator EAT, PAY, WAIT;

private void Start()
{
    EAT = EatPizza();
    WAIT = WaitForPizza();
    PAY = WaitForTheCase();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pizza"))
    {
        canEat = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Out"))
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (isEating)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, agent.destination) <= 1f)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("sit");
            isEating = false;
        }
    }

    if (!isEating && !isPaying && !isOut && !canEat)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitForPizza());
    }

    if (!isEating && !isPaying && !isOut && canEat)
    {
        StopCoroutine(WAIT);
        StartCoroutine(EatPizza());
    }

    if (isPaying)
    {
        isEating = false;
        anim.SetTrigger("walk");
        
        agent.destination = checkoutTarget.position;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, agent.destination) <= 1f)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("wait");
            if (ifCashier)
            {
                //throw money 
                isPaying = false;

                isOut = true;
            }

            if (!ifCashier)
            {
                StartCoroutine(WaitForTheCase());
            }
        }
    }

    if (isOut)
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("walk");
        isEating = false;
        isPaying = false;
        
        agent.destination = outTarget.position;
    }

    if (canEat)
    {
        StopCoroutine(WAIT);
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitForTheCase()
{
    anim.SetTrigger("wait");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(randomFloatWait);
    angry.SetActive(true);
    
    isEating = false;
    isPaying = false;
    isOut = true;
}

IEnumerator EatPizza()
{
    angry.SetActive(false);
    StopCoroutine(WaitForPizza());
    happy.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(randomFloatWait);
    
    happy.SetActive(false);
    isEating = false;
    isPaying = true;
    isOut = false;
}

IEnumerator WaitForPizza()
{
    while (!canEat)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(randomFloatWait);
        angry.SetActive(true);
    
        isEating = false;
        isPaying = false;
        isOut = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Logically it has to be one of `!isEating && !isPaying && !isOut && canEat`. Do you know how to breakpoint and debug Unity in Visual studio?

Comment: Nope, I can say for myself too new. @Absinthe

Comment: Literally search "unity debug visual studio".

Comment: in general instead of using a bunch of bool flags have you considered to rather use an `enum` and use `switch - case` ("state-machine") it would probably clarify a lot of things in your code

Answer (score 0):

First, define `WAIT` as `Coroutine` then when you want to start waiting use `WAIT = StartCoroutine(WaitForPizza());` and when you want to finish it use `StopCoroutine(WAIT);`.